# Is there a way to print certain unicode characters in python terminal from Windows?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, terminal

So I have been trying to print in my terminal using Python the following Unicode characters:

```
def printUnicode():
    print(u"\u2b1c")
    print(u"\u1f7e8")
    print(u"\u1f7e9")
```

However, this is my output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY9lc.png.

Even though I checked that I was using UTF-8 (chcp=65001), I do not why I cannot show those characters. Idk if there is something wrong my PC configuration, the code or it just impossible to print them in windows cmd.

Comment: You need a font which supports such characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have wrong escape sequences in your [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
import unicodedata   # access to the Unicode Character Database

def check_unicode(s):
    print(len(s), s)
    for char in s:
        print( char, '{:04x}'.format( ord(char)), 
               unicodedata.category( char),
               unicodedata.name( char, '(unknown)') )
```

**Output**:

```
check_unicode( u"\u2b1c\u1f7e8\u1f7e9") # original string literals
```

> ```
> 5 ⬜὾8὾9
> ⬜ 2b1c So WHITE LARGE SQUARE
> ὾ 1f7e Cn (unknown)
> 8 0038 Nd DIGIT EIGHT
> ὾ 1f7e Cn (unknown)
> 9 0039 Nd DIGIT NINE
> ```

```
check_unicode( u"\u2b1c\U0001f7e8\U0001f7e9") # adjusted string literals
```

> ```
> 3 ⬜
> ⬜ 2b1c So WHITE LARGE SQUARE
>  1f7e8 So LARGE YELLOW SQUARE
>  1f7e9 So LARGE GREEN SQUARE
> ```

**Edit.** Run in Windows Terminal using default [Cascadia Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/cascadia-code) font…

Comment: Now I am trying to pring the adjusted string literals. The system seems to recognize them, however I still get the "?" symbol when I try to print the yellow and the green square in my windows terminal. Im both using Cascadia Code Font and  chcp=65001. Did you make any additional configuration?

Comment: I'm running it in `wt.exe` [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) not in `cmd.exe` where I get [Glyph 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph) as well instead of coloured squares…